# connecting android with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, android, client-server, application-design

hey guys i am developing a final year location-based project(gps) in android.I have to create a server using php and mysql which contains name and location(in latitude and longitude) of important hospitals in Mumbai.The android client should be able to retrieve the the latitude and longitude of locations in mysql(external) database and then plot it on a google map.

Could u plzz tell me whether this is possible?If yes, then how?
Any help would be appreciated....cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your projject would in fact consist of two application. A client running on android, and a server php-mysql application. The client would most likely talk to server using standard http requests.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for using the PHP/MySQL combination to achieve this? Unless the list of hospitals is very dynamic it would be far more convenient to just but the data in an SQLite database that Android comes with.

If this is no an option I would put up a simple web service from where you could retrieve your data.

Comment: I'm assuming the reason for this is that it's `a final year [...] project`. They quite often don't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method out. I will be using this method for the current project i am working on.

You basically create a php script on a server and use http posts to send the data to the script, read the tutorial linked below for better explanation.

[mysql/android tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)